# how to replace route and refresh in react router 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am thinking of not using window reload() but only react router 4 after this code:

```
this.props.history.push('/myPath')
```

then refresh the browser, is there a way to refresh the browser with react router 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `location.reload();`. There's no need for `react-router` to refresh.

Taken from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820884/1913185)

Comment: this works, i was trying to find a way by using react router 4 not this, I hope there was

Comment: in the linked question, there are several ways to do it. Some of them are through `react-router`. The top answer was not through `react-router`, which happened to be the one I added. You should read through the answers to the linked question.