# Router push not working from within useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have the following component where I am expecting to go to another path via `router's push method immediately cos router push is inside the` useEffect` hook.

But router push never seems to happen. The `ShowLoading` component is just a loading screen (shows a loading spinner).

The page is just stuck on the loading spinner screen.

What am I doing wrong, why am I not being pushed to the new page? Pls advice. Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { ShowLoading } from '../../ShowLoading';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = ({
  router: { push, location },
}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {    
    // this cookie gets set thus clearly we are entering this useEffect. 
    Cookies.set('temp', '1');

    const value = 'test';
    const params = location.search ? `${location.search}` : '';

    // seems like this has no effect, no pushing and moving to new page path. 
    push(`/${value}/my_path${params}`);

  }, []);
  return (<ShowLoading />);
};

export default (withRouter(MyComponent);
```

P.S: Goes to a new path as expected if I do the following but looking to do it via a router.

```
window.location.pathname = `/${value}/my_path${params}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get `match`, `history` and `location` as props when using `withRouter`. So you can get the push from `history` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { ShowLoading } from '../../ShowLoading';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

const MyComponent = ({
  history,
  location
}) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {    
    // this cookie gets set thus clearly we are entering this useEffect. 
    Cookies.set('temp', '1');

    const value = 'test';
    const params = location.search ? `${location.search}` : '';

    history.push(`/${value}/my_path${params}`);

  }, []);
  return (<ShowLoading />);
};

export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Comment: If I do this, the spinner stops but I stay on same page. I also no longer set the cookie for some reason.

Comment: Does the params value correspond with that you're looking for? Try logging it on the console

Comment: I am actually on the same path currently, example - /value/my_path?param=1. From here, I just want to go back to same path again - /value/my_path?param=1. Something like a refresh, where due to the cookie being set, now some other actions takes place due to refresh.

Comment: window.location.pathname = ... works for this refresh. But I am losing some tracking values due to that thus trying to use React Router instead.

Comment: Oh, you just want to refresh the page?? try history.go(0)
You can also check out this section for possible answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820682/how-do-i-reload-a-page-with-react-router

Comment: But if I use history.go(0), wouldn't that essentially be same as window.location.pathname = ...  which loses tracking information for me.

Comment: On a second thought, I read your question again and wondered why you need to refresh exactly when you can actually have a function that can achieve what you want after the cookie has been set. Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Its some logic we have in place where if we enter this component (coming from another component), meant to do the redirect. Due to the way it is setup, need to do it via a component.