# How to refresh page with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to refresh page on click using React Router.

I know, I could use `window.location.reload();`

But I would like to use some magic from React Router. There is a way to refresh page with React Router or should I use a normal method from window object?

Comment: What do you want refreshing the page to achieve? A real browser refresh will reload the page (potentially partly from cache), a refresh inside the router may/may not reset some components state depending on how they are set up.

Comment: @DBS Let's say I need to refresh page to repeat database query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reload a page with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820682/how-do-i-reload-a-page-with-react-router)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using react-router v6 then try this (take this as an example), it might works!

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();

const refreshPage = () => {
  navigate(0);
}
```

If you are using old then try this!

Just put that attribute on your Router, and whenever you are on a new Path it will force the page to reload itself.

```
<Router forceRefresh={true}>
```

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/ProtectedRoute";

import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Keywords from "./pages/Admin/Modulos/Keyword";
import MainPage from "./pages/MainPage";

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/ingresar"
            element={<Login />}
          ></Route>
        
          <Route
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute
                isAllowed={true}
                redirectTo="/ingresar"
              ></ProtectedRoute>
            }
          >
            <Route path="/admin/keyword" element={<Keywords />}></Route>

          </Route>

          <Route path="*" element={<MainPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProtectedRoute.js

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ProtectedRoute({
  children,
  isAllowed,
  redirectTo = "/ingresar",
}) {
  const location = useLocation();

  if(location.state!=undefined){
    console.log("hola748")
    return <Navigate to={location.state} replace></Navigate>;
  }
  if (!isAllowed) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectTo} replace></Navigate>;
  }

  return children ? children : <Outlet />;
}
```

And to refresh (from Keywords.js) use

```
navigate("/admin/keyword",{state:"/admin/keyword"});
```