# Force window.location.reload() one time while switching routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

useEffect Hook execute 3 lifecycle i.e., **[componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and ComponentWillUnmount]**.

With this I am trying to reload my page only once if `Country` page is visited..

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-nash-rc98mw?file=/src/index.js

**Question:** How to make this working using Route.

```
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" Component={App} />
      <Route path="/country" Component={Country} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

If Can help answering the following POST. I'd appreciate it.

https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/754

[image]

**SO SOLUTION I CAN THINK OF IS**

RELOAD THE PAGE.

I have created my Custom element using `react-to-webcomponent`

Comment: Why are you reloading every time `App` is rendered?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You have coded an infinite loop here.

Comment: @Unmitigated So I wanted to load ```Country``` page one time whenever it is visited/routed. May I know how to achieve this.?

Comment: What's the issue with your code now? `/country` shows the Country component.

Comment: Issue faced by me is while rendering an External Web Components in my React Project. No one was able to answer on how to remove a customElement if defined once. So my only solution is to reload the page so a custom element will get removed```

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Unmitigated if you think so then please answer to this problem https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/754

Comment: @Unmitigated And that is the reason why I want to reload the page so to again define my element since I cannot remove it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you please help me to reload the page once if Country is visited. Is it even possible to do that. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @BhokluSingh why are you re-defining a custom web component? Are you doing it because they are changing on the fly?

Comment: @chq I am not redefining a custom element. . Whenever a component having custom-element is mounted, that custom element gets defined once. .So when that component is demounted, the same custom-element is not removed by React. On visiting the same component again, React tries to define the custom-element which was earlier defined. Here it throws errors saying that you cannot define an existing custom element. The solution is to reload the page.

Comment: @BhokluSingh reloading is an anty pattern. React is specificy made to avoid reloading, and work on a single page application.

Comment: @BhokluSing Its really strange that you are using HTML Custom Elements and React on the same application... but since you are already working in an anti-pattern, what you should do is just hide the error with a try-catch instead of making user experience worse by reloading.

Comment: @chq- On visiting ComponentA having ```React-Custom-Ele-One``` first time all works well. Now I wanted to switch to ComponentB having ```React-Custom-Ele-Two```.  Even now its working as expected. Now If I try to navigate to  ComponentA having ```React-Custom-Ele-One``` the page stops responding. . And the error in the console saying ```cannot refine custom element```. . So now on reloading the page, I can view the componentA.

Comment: Insulting those who are trying to help you is not a good path towards an answer.  The reason for the poor response here is that you have described your problem extremely poorly.  If you need a reload, then you have a bug in your Javascript code that is causing an element to be redefined, but since you haven't shown that to us, what can we possibly do?

Comment: @TimRoberts And I do not see any bug in my JavaScript code. It works extremely well in Wordpress pages or other HTML pages. I exported my web component using ```react-to-webcomponent``` library as seen above.

Answer (score 1):

I should be solved with: `forceRefresh={true}`

```
<Route path="/country" forceRefresh={true} Component={Country} />
```

More info here:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/react-router-quick/9781789532555/233f59d9-5f18-4ea8-a7f9-cd9b27435025.xhtml

But found the suggestion in stack overflow here:
[How to refresh page with React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218944/how-to-refresh-page-with-react-router)

Im not able to verify it since I need the console.log() that was not available on the sandbox.

However as was pointed out in the comments of the question. I think this a bad workaround for another bug in the code (That was not included in your example that should probably be solved instead). With reload the whole page you lose the benefits of React.

Comment: I appreciate your response. But I have tried all these before posting my question. Nevertheless I am going to create a demo project and re-post this question so that helpers can see the actual error which I am facing. Thanks